# Schengen visa refused,

Tags: visa-refusals, schengen-visas

I applied for france visa, however it was refused stating the justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable.

I later realised that I have made a lot of mistakes, like my bank statement had issues, my accomoodation details didn't had proper reference numbers and i failed to attach my travel itinerary. Also, my cover letter had nothing except two lines that I want visa.

I understood I made mistakes, and I have applied for second time. Please suggest what things I need to be careful. Also, what are the chances, I am very scared that this will ruin all my travel plans